# The class in Item can`t be recognized after building a python scrapy program

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to build a scrapy project according to a book.
After using 'scrapy startproject tutorial/cd tutorial/scrapy genspider quotes 
quotes.toscrape.coom' comands and adding the parse function & changing items, the detail code as fellow:

quotes.py:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import QuoteItem


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.css('.quote')
        for quote in quotes:
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('.text::text').extract_first()
            item['author'] = quote.css('.author::text').extract_first()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('.tags .tag::text').extract()
            yield item

        next = response.css('.pager .next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        url = response.urljoin(next)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy


class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):

    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
```

The class QuoteItem cann`t be recognized in quotes.py 
[error prompt picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Xan.png)

And after I changed to 'from tutorial.tutorial.items import QuoteItem'
and run 'scrapy crawl quotes', there is another error as fellow:
[error again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IRSD.png)

And this caused the results can`t be saved. Someone can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine with that code!! try using **scrapy runspider yourspiderfile.py** instead of scrapy crawl quotes.There is no error in the code.

Comment: Thanks, I just don`t know why the pycharm can`t recongnized 'QuoteItem'

Comment: Try with terminal then,If it works there ,pycharm is raising the error!!

Answer (score 0):

[From Scrapy Tutorial:](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/intro/tutorial.html)

*To put our spider to work, go to the project’s top level directory and run:
scrapy crawl quotes*

In new version Scrapy, please go to the top directory:

```
scrapy runspider xx/spiders/xxx.py(the full path from top level directory)
```

In your xxx.py, make sure you import the item like this:

```
from xx.items import xxItem
# (remember to import the right class name, not always QuoteItem)
```

**Pay attention**

It's recommended to run scrapy on linux system or WSL. It does not work well on Win. If you meet the problem like the spider is not found, it may be the system issue.